# Easy raycasting game

Tags: 3d, raycasting

You know Wolfenstein 3D from 1992, yeah, I really like that style of games, where It's 3D, but It's really just 2D.

I would like to create a game, similar to Wolfenstein 3D, with raycasting. But I do not know how, and where to start.

First. which program to use to make it.
second. what coding language
third. add game mechanics

If I am successful, I would like to obtain knowledge on how to add textures to the game, and if I can make it an EXE file, so you can just run the EXE and  you can play the game.

I have tried many tutorials, but some aren't clear, some don't say what program they use, and some just do not work.

I am very ready to give up. but I also don't want to at the same time.

I have wanted to make a game. raycasting 3d or not raycasting. but it is what I want to do.

Any help appreciated

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: The source code has been [publicly available](https://github.com/id-Software/wolf3d) for a long time. I'm sure there are other ray-casting engines out there that don't rely on as much assembly, and you'd be better off using OpenGL / D3D for rendering anyway. As it is, your question is too broad.

Comment: Even if you end up using OpenGL/D3D/etc, implementing some 3D-like graphics feature without such "3D graphic library" as your first try will be good way to learn some necessary basis.

Such a step may seem just roundabout, but It is useful to avoid the difficulty of learning mathematics/algorithm and library specific specifications/usage/etc at the same time without confusing them.